# Cannot update Entity Framework model after schema name change

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I am on a project that has an EF model that was created with a schema of 'dbo'.  At some point in time the schema was changed to something more meaningful.  However, try as I may I cannot now update from the database with the newly named schema as all the entities create new objects instead of updating the current ones.  For example instead of Person, I now get and Person1.  I have tried to edit connection strings as well as the EDMX file but nothing seems to be working.

Is there anyway to get my model to update from the database with the renamed schema?

I am using EF 6.0 and .Net 4.5.

Comment: have you tried to delete everything from the current EF model before updating it?

Comment: I'm not sure if this is relevant or not, but I remember having issues with the Model Generator in Visual Studio 2012. If you're using VS2012, make sure you have Update 3 installed.

Comment: In this case, I'd just edit the edmx file in a text editor and replace "dbo" by the new schema name.

Comment: I did try doing that. Editing the edmx file and replacing "dbo".  It is still broken though.  I think that the best thing for me to do is see if I can't get a copy of the original db from backups.

Comment: This was a boneheaded move on my part.  I tried to recreate on my local '.' instance, i.e. 'Generate database from model' and did not realize that it had pluralized all the names of my tables.  Therefore the model and the newly created database were out of sync, with one set of tables not ending in s'es and the other with.  I tried to turn this off when I generated the script but did not figure it out and just ended up hand editing the script.  Perhaps there is a good reason for generating a table 'PERs' for the entity 'PER' but I can't think of it.